# What is the fastest data set class to bind to a GridView control?

Tags: winforms, gridview, datatable, dataset, datareader

I am creating a Windows Application in C# using Visual Studio 2008. When I click on a CheckedListBox item, I want to fill a GridView.

What I want to know is which works faster: a DataSet, DataTable, or DataReader? In my computer, I only have 512 MB of RAM, and the record is more than 20 lakh.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, DataReader is always faster.  DataSet and DataTable are layers of abstraction on top of DataReader.

Comment: Why does the fact that other classes extend `DataReader` make it the fastest? Beyond that, how are you going to instantiate an instance of the `DataReader` class, given that it's marked as abstract?

Comment: DataTable and DataSet do not extend / inherit from DataReader.  Behind the scenes, they are populated by forward-only DataReaders.  See http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/dataset-datareader.

Comment: Notice, of course, that the "DataReader" class the linked article is talking about is actually **`SqlDataReader`**, which is not exactly the same thing as [`DataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.aspx).

Comment: Because the post is about GridViews, DataSets, and DataReaders, I was assuming that we were talking about objects in the System.Data namespace.  I had not heard of this AdoDotNetDataReader class that lives in the Microsoft.VisualStudio namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165128.aspx.  Interesting!

Comment: Yeah, I originally thought it was ASP.NET because of the reference to a `GridView`. But since he says inline that it's a "Windows Application", I assumed that couldn't be the case. Not really sure, but I made the edits that seemed right to me.